# Akka unit testing strategies without mocks

Tags: scala, unit-testing, akka, akka-testkit

**MAIN IDEA**: How can we unit test (or re-factor to facilitate unit testing) Akka actors with fairly complex business logic?

I have been using Akka for a project at my company (some very basic stuff is in production) and have been continuously re-factoring my actors, researching, and experimenting with Akka testkit to see if I can get it right...

Basically, most of the reading I've done casually says "Man, all you need is the testkit. If you're using mocks you're doing it wrong!!" however the docs and examples are so light that I find a number of questions that are not covered (basically their examples are pretty contrived classes that have 1 method & interacts with no other actors, or only in trivial ways like input output at end of method). As an aside, if anyone can point me to a test suite for an akka app with any reasonable amount of complexity, I'd really appreciate it.

Here I will now at least attempt to detail some specific cases & would like to know what one would call the "Akka-certified" approach (but please nothing vague... I'm looking for the Roland Kuhn style methodology, if he were ever to actually dive in-depth to specific issues). I will accept strategies that involve refactoring, but please note my anxieties towards this mentioned in the scenarios.

**Scenario 1 : Lateral methods (method calling another in the same actor)**

```
case class GetProductById(id : Int)
case class GetActiveProductsByIds(ids : List[Int])

class ProductActor(val partsActor : ActorRef, inventoryActor : ActorRef) extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case GetProductById(pId) => pipe(getProductById(pId)) to sender
    case GetActiveProductsByIds(pIds) => pipe(getActiveProductsByIds(pIds)) to sender
  }

  def getProductById(id : Int) : Future[Product] = {
    for {
      // Using pseudo-code here
      parts <- (partsActor ? GetPartsForProduct(id)).mapTo[List[Part]]
      instock <- (inventoryActor ? StockStatusRequest(id)).mapTo[Boolean]
      product <- Product(parts, instock)
    } yield product
  }

  def getActiveProductsByIds(ids : List[Int]) : Future[List[Product]] = {
    for {
      activeProductIds <- (inventoryActor ? FilterActiveProducts(ids)).mapTo[List[Int]]
      activeProducts <- Future.sequence(activeProductIds map getProductById)
    } yield activeProducts
  }
}
```

So, basically here we have what are essentially 2 fetch method, one singular and one for multiple. In the singular case, testing is simple. We set up a TestActorRef, inject some probes in the constructor and just make sure that the right message chain is firing.

My anxiety here comes from the multiple fetch method. It involves a filtering step (to fetch only active product IDs). Now, in order to test this, I can set up the same scenario (TestActorRef of ProductActor with probes replacing the actors called for in the constructor). However, to test the message passing flow I have to mock all of the message chaining for not only the response to FilterActiveProducts but all of the ones that have already been covered by the previous test of the "getProductById" method (not really unit testing then, is it?). Clearly this can spiral out of control in terms of the amount of message mocking necessary, and it would be far easier to verify (through mocks?) that this method simply gets called for every ID that survives the filter.

Now, I understand this can be solved by extracting out another actor (create a ProductCollectorActor that gets for multiple IDs, and simply calls down to the ProductActor with a single message request for each ID that passes the filter). However, I've calculated this & if I were to do extractions like this for every hard-to-test set of sibling methods I have I will end up with dozens of actors for relatively small amount of domain objects. The amount of boilerplate overhead would be a lot, plus the system will be considerably more complex (many more actors just perform what are essentially some method compositions).

**Aside : Inline (static) logic**

One way I've tried to settle this is by moving inline (basically anything that is more than a very simple control flow) into the companion or another singleton object. For example, if there was a method in the above method that was to filter out products unless they matched a certain type, I might do something like the following:

```
object ProductActor {
  def passthroughToysOnly(products : List[Product]) : List[Toy] =
    products flatMap {p => 
      p.category match {
        case "toy" => Some(p)
        case _ => None
      }
    }
}
```

This can be unit tested in isolation pretty well, and can actually allow for testing of pretty complex units so long as they don't call out to other actors. I'm not a huge fan of putting these far from the logic that uses them (should I put it in the actual actor & then test by calling underlyingActor?).

Overall, it still leads to the problem that in doing more naive message-passing based tests in the methods that actually call this, I essentially have to edit all my message expectations to reflect how the data will be transformed by these 'static' (I know they're not technically static in Scala but bear with me) methods. This I guess I can live with since it's a realistic part of unit testing (in a method that calls several others, we are probably checking the gestalt combinatorial logic in the presence of test data with varying properties).

Where this all really breaks down for me is here --

**Scenario 2 : Recursive algorithms**

```
case class GetTypeSpecificProductById(id : Int)

class TypeSpecificProductActor(productActor : ActorRef, bundleActor : ActorRef) extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case GetTypeSpecificProductById(pId) => pipe(getTypeSpecificProductById(pId)) to sender
  }

  def getTypeSpecificProductById(id : Int) : Future[Product] = {
    (productActor ? GetProductById(id)).mapTo[Product] flatMap (p => p.category match {
        case "toy" => Toy(p.id, p.name, p.color)
        case "bundle" => 
          Bundle(p.id, p.name, 
            getProductsInBundle((bundleActor ? GetProductIdsForBundle(p.id).mapTo[List[Int]))
      }
    )
  }

  def getProductsInBundle(ids : List[Int]) : List[Product] =
    ids map getProductById
}
```

So yes there is a bit of pseudocode here but the gist is that now we have a recursive method (getProductId is calling out to getProductsById in the case of a bundle, which is again calling getProductId). With mocking, there are points where we could cut off recursion to make things more testable. But even that is complex due to the fact that there are actor calls within certain pattern-matches in the method.

This is really the perfect storm for me.... extracting the match for the "bundle" case into a lower actor may be promising, but then also means that we now need to deal with circular dependency (bundleAssembly actor needs typeSpecificActor which needs bundleAssembly...).

This may be testable via pure message mocking (creating stub messages where I can gauge what level of recursion they will have & carefully designing this message sequence) but it will be pretty complex & worse if more logic is required than a single extra actor call for the bundle type.

**Remarks**

Thanks ahead of time for any help! I am actually very passionate about minimal, testable, well-designed code and am afraid that if I try to achieve everything via extraction I will still have circular issues, still not be able to really test any inline/combinatorial logic & my code will be 1000x more verbose than it could have been with lots of boilerplate for tiny single-to-the-extreme-responsibility actors. Essentially, the code will all be written around test structure.

I am also very cautious about over-engineered tests, because if they are testing intricate message sequences rather than method calls (which I'm not sure how to expect simple semantic calls except with mocks) the tests may succeed but won't really be a true unit tests of core method functionality. Instead it will just be a direct reflection of control flow constructs in the code (or the message passing system).

So maybe it is that I am asking too much of unit testing, but please if you have some wisdom set me straight!

Comment: Your tests might be too granular. Tests should test for, and, in a way, document business logic. So, one way is to write tests against the contract that your service provides. Unit tests that are written to test particular implementation details can make refactoring difficult. You can end up spending most of time fixing your unit tests.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I think in a way you could be right. However, my understanding of the utility of unit tests is that if you break your application up into proper units they can each have some semantic meaning & be tested in isolation. Then, the codebase can be considered extremely reliable even when there are few tests to cover the outer integrations (since they will all be somewhat linear compositions of units). And in many cases (like building a lib or API) there will no be outer integrations to test (these are all user code) so you really have nothing BUT units.

Comment: So my qunadry re: testing in Akka is really that I want to unit test (outer method testing involves too much combinatorial data / message-passing) but I want the unit tests to have semantic value (not be arbitrarily granular, as I mention in closing remark).

Comment: Also, I believe this overhead is mainly coming from the need to deal with testing paradigms for async/sync & message-passing/pure-methods in the same context yet needing to treat each somewhat differently. It's essentially that I feel the code/testing is being dictated more by the system than the nature of the code's logic itself. The dichotomy between TestActorRefs & their underlyingActor is a good example of this (it seems using underlyingActor is mostly discouraged, though seemingly not as vehemently as using mocks).

Comment: I've done plenty of unit testing of single actors with mocks. It pays off if your actors are fairly complicated (complex state machines, FSMs, etc). Just be careful with mock validation and futures.

Comment: hm... cool. mind explaining what kind of mocks you were using / how you injected them? I was thinking of grabbing underlyingActor with testkit & trying to apply a partial mock over some methods (with a Mockito spy I guess?). Hoping this doesn't choke since actor is coming through some of Akka system factory methods.

Comment: you don't want to test private methods. Everything that is not in the public contract (from a messaging point of view) is private. If you have too many internal branches you maybe need to split your actor in two or more. I think that feeling the need to Test internal methods is a smell. If an actor has injected dependencies that are not actors themselves (e.g. dao or whatever) you can mock those by simply passing the mock to the actor props (i.e. constructor)

Comment: @TrustNoOne thanks but I already do pass in mocks for DAO actors, use lots of test probes. I test complex private methods but wouldn't necessarily include in codebase test suite if it is really just making sure a granular method's code works. If you read the cases outlined above, my issue is really what you mention -- "maybe need to split your actor in two or more". Is this really the solution, to have almost an actor per method in the scenarios I describe?

Comment: not necessarily one per method, I guess the right size depends on each case, there's no one-size-fits-all solution. Ideally, the smaller the better, but with actors (i.e. message passing) you incur in a heavy overhead that you don't have when your unit of work is a class with one public method (or even better a function). The idea is that you don't have to think about the internal methods. It's just implementation details. Try and TDD your actors: you will only define the interfaces and the tests for them. Try a contract-first approach and see if it works for you

Comment: That's the approach I was trying initially, but found issues like in scenario #1. It's easy to test the contract of the singlular fetch ("does it pass out the correct messages to other actors?"). But multiple fetch test will then be a superset (does it execute the actions of the singular fetch, for each ID requested). This seems redundant, and actually strange that the tests are only verifying a sequence of requests to other actors. Is this simply the accepted paradigm? And must I then extract the singular fetch to a lower actor if I want to view it as 1 message expectation per ID? thx again!

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with your statement "I'm not a huge fan of putting these far from the logic that uses them".

I find this to be an essential component of unit testing and code organization.

Jamie Allen, in *Effective Akka*, states the following about externalizing business logic (emphasis mine):

> This has a few added benefits.  First of all, not only can we we **write
>   useful unit tests**, but we can also get meaningful stack traces that
>   say the name where the failure occurred in the function.  It also
>   prevents us from closing over external state, since everything must be
>   passed as an operand to it.  Plus, we can build libraries of reusable
>   functions that reduce code duplication.

When writing code I take it a step further than your example and move the business logic into a separate package:

```
package businessLogic

object ProductGetter {
  def passthroughToysOnly(products : List[Product]) : List[Toy] =
    products flatMap {p => 
      p.category match {
        case "toy" => Some(p)
        case _ => None
    }
  }
}
```

This allows for changing the concurrency methodology to Futures, Java threads, or even some not yet created concurrency library without having to refactor my business logic.  The business logic packages become the "what" of the code, the akka libraries become the "how".

If you isolate the business logic then all receive methods become simple "routers" of messages to external functions.  Therefore, if you hammer at your business logic with unit tests the only testing you need to do of your Actors is to ensure the case patterns are matching correctly.

Addressing your specific problem: I would remove the `getActiveProductsByIds` from the Actor.  If the user of the Actor wants to only get active products leave it to them to filter the ids first.  Your Actor should do 1 thing only: `GetProductById`.  Quoting Allen again:

> It is very easy to make an actor perform addition tasks - we simply
>   add new messages to its receive block to allow it to perform more and
>   different kinds of work.  However, doing so limits your ability to
>   compose systems of actors and define contextual grouping.  Keep your
>   actors focused on a single kind of work, and in doing so, allow
>   yourself to use them flexibly.

Comment: I agree with your statement about moving business logic away. In fact, in my real application logic such as type filtering is done on the Product object itself (or in another actor if it involves more actor interactions). The scenarios are contrived pseudocode in order to point out many issues, I admit. I agree that a filtering fetch belongs in a different actor but if you look at that method imagining no filter, the issue remains. If I move it simply to test multi-fetch there will be many such actors (ProductCollectorActor, ProductFilterActor). Classes essentially only to facilitate tests.

Comment: In essence, there will be no "Actor System" style gain from having these in multiple actors, it's just a heavier app with many actor layers to accomplish some small DAO callouts.

Comment: @jm0 My primary point was that if you have isolated business logic and test it thoroughly then the Actor tests can be rather simplistic, basically just type checking tests on the receive method.

Comment: Yeah but I already mention in my aside that I'm doing this (was small question about placement but clear that I'm already extracting away 'static' logic). The heart of my issue is the two scenarios, explaining problem cases in pure message passing tests being very redundant and coupled to repetitive message sequences or requiring arbitrary levels of extraction with no technical gain (probable loss, since actors occur overhead).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is a very interesting question. Akka documentation is very good in general, and the [testing](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/testing.html) part has many insightful notes along the way to avoid common pitfalls and suggesting best practices.

The other day I was [reading about this](https://bionicspirit.com/blog/2015/12/15/avoid-javaisms-code-smell.html), and found a suggestion that I didn't try before: using the [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). The idea is to leave your Actors to only care about messaging (which you don't need to test, Akka team will do it for you ;) and broadcast events to subscribers. This way your logic gets completely isolated from Actors, hence making it much easier to test.

Note:
I haven't tried this in a production system, but since you mentioned that only very basic stuff is in your production system this might be worth a shot.